# Table CSS Padding, Cellspacing, etc

Tags: html, css

My two custom social buttons. I put them inside a table and set them to in-line block but there's a big space in between both of them! How do I close this gap? I've set the table to a class name of "share." I want to edit through the style-sheet because I don't want to go through every single page and edit its code.

```
<table class="share">
<tr style="background-color: white;">
<td style="border: none;">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+escape(location.href));likePop();" class="fb-share" style="text-decoration:none"><span style="padding:10px; font-size:15px; text-align: center; background-color:#3B5998; font-weight:bold; font-family: Verdana; color:white; border-radius:10px;">Share on Facebook</span></a></span></span></p>
</td>
<td style="border: none;">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text='+window.og_title+'&amp;url='+escape(location.href));" class="tw-share" style="text-decoration:none"><span style="padding:10px; font-size:15px; text-align: center; background-color:#55acee; font-weight:bold; font-family: Verdana; color:white; border-radius:10px;">Tweet</span></a></span></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: example: http://thequizmania.com/what-type-of-girl-are-you/

Comment: Please provide you css code and html code so we know what you are trying to do

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: The table with class="share" has a width of 500px.

Comment: @RichBailo I posted it

Comment: "Not using a table" for this would be a good start. It doesn't look remotely like a tabular data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok from what i see you are going to have a hard time just doing css, as you have styles within your Html tags already.

CSS: this will make them but up together. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/h1qevfax/11/)

```
table { 
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
td { 
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: No Problem glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution in your case is to change the table style to `display:block;` and it should get the `td`'s closer.

Comment: still same thing. not working. i posted my code though.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.share {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: i posted my code. Do you think you have a better way to rewrite it to fit perfectly and most importantly mobile friendly